# Ajax jquery versus angularjs in javafx webview

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, javafx, webview

I perform a `jquery ajax get` authenticated request in a `javafx WebView`. This is the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myServer/myWS",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('cookie', 'JSESSIONID=F769C2D14D87F4DB7395EF3C67E3C9A8');
    }
  });
```

This request **works** perfectly.

Now, I would like to perform the same request by using an `Angularjs $http get` request. I tried this:

```
var config = {
            headers: {
             'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'cookie': 'JSESSIONID=F769C2D14D87F4DB7395EF3C67E3C9A8'             
             },
            withCredentials: true
          };
$http.get('https://myServer/myWS', config)
```

It does not work and returns a **401 error** "Full authentication is required to access this resource".

What's wrong with this `Angularjs $http` request ?

By the way, I noticed that `Angularjs $cookies` does not seem to work properly in `javafx WebView`.

Comment: Why are you setting the data property in the config. With GET requests it should be `undefined`. Also `withCredentials` is a config property, not a header property. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).